# SQL server to do like Group By task

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with SQL server as below,

```
Date        Value
---------------------------------------------------
08-01-2016    1
08-02-2016    1
08-03-2016    1
08-04-2016    1
08-05-2016    1
08-06-2016    2
08-07-2016    2
08-08-2016    2
08-09-2016    2.5
08-10-2016    1
08-11-2016    1
```

Since the original table is too large, even I used 'Results to file', it still raise the exception 'System.OutOfMemoryException'. That's why I want to organize the table into this kind.

But I don't have a good logic to deal with. Therefore, I want to change the table into this kind as below.

```
Date_from      Date_to      Value
-------------------------------------------------
08-01-2016     08-05-2016   1
08-06-2016     08-08-2016   2
08-09-2016     08-09-2016   2.5
08-10-2016     08-11-2016   1
```

I appreciate your ideas!

Comment: can you try and explain your logic for how you're grouping the data?

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: @Prdp SQL server 2014 management studio

Comment: Are you using this in an app (VB or C#) ? Handling this in your code can work and not throw an "Out of Memory" exception. Otherwise, you'll need a stored procedure where you'll iterate through all records to build your result.

Comment: @DForck42 You mean how I get this kind of result? I cannot, so I ask you guys for ideas~ Thank you~

Answer (score 5):

Commonly called as *Groups and Island problem*. Here is one trick to do this

```
;WITH data
    AS (SELECT *,Lag(Value, 1)OVER(ORDER BY Dates) [pVal]
        FROM   (VALUES ('08-01-2016',1 ),
                    ('08-02-2016',1 ),
                    ('08-03-2016',1 ),
                    ('08-04-2016',1 ),
                    ('08-05-2016',1 ),
                    ('08-06-2016',2 ),
                    ('08-07-2016',2 ),
                    ('08-08-2016',2 ),
                    ('08-09-2016',2.5 ),
                    ('08-10-2016',1 ),
                    ('08-11-2016',1 )) tc (Dates, Value)),
     intr
     AS (SELECT Dates,
                Value,
                Sum(Iif(pVal = Value, 0, 1)) OVER(ORDER BY Dates) AS [Counter]
         FROM   data)
SELECT Min(Dates) AS Dates_from,
       Max(Dates) AS Dates_to,
       Value
FROM   intr
GROUP  BY [Counter],
          Value
```

Answer (score 2):

The cumulative sum/lag approach is one method.  In this case, a simpler method is:

```
select min(date) as date_from, max(date) as date_to, value
from (select t.*,
             dateadd(day, - row_number() over (partition by value order by date),date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by value, grp;
```

This uses the observation that the dates are consecutive with no gaps.  Hence, subtracting a sequence from the date will yield a constant -- when the `value`s are the same.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff - Sorry,I declare value data type as INT Now I declared value datatype as decimal then check.It's works fine.

Comment: @Mansoor . . . This seems like the simplest solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    [Date] DATE,
    [Value] DECIMAL(9,2)
)

INSERT @T VALUES
( '08-01-2016', 1 ),
( '08-02-2016', 1 ),
( '08-03-2016', 1 ),
( '08-04-2016', 1 ),
( '08-05-2016', 1 ),
( '08-06-2016', 2 ),
( '08-07-2016', 2 ),
( '08-08-2016', 2 ),
( '08-09-2016', 2.5 ),
( '08-10-2016', 1 ),
( '08-11-2016', 1 )

SELECT * FROM @T

SELECT A.[Date] StartDate, B.[Date] EndDate, A.[Value] FROM (
    SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.[Date], A.[Value]) O FROM @T A
    LEFT JOIN @T B ON B.[Value] = A.[Value] AND B.[Date] = DATEADD(d, -1, A.[Date])
    WHERE B.[Date] IS NULL
) A
JOIN (
    SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.[Date], A.[Value]) O FROM @T A
    LEFT JOIN @T B ON B.[Value] = A.[Value] AND B.[Date] = DATEADD(d, 1, A.[Date])
    WHERE B.[Date] IS NULL
) B ON B.O = A.O
```

Answer (score 1):

Prdp's solution is great but just in case if anyone is still using SQL Server 2008 where LAG() and The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not available here is an alternative:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp;

CREATE TABLE #Temp([Dates] DATE
              , [Value] FLOAT);

INSERT INTO      #Temp([Dates]
                 , [Value])
VALUES
      ('08-01-2016'
     , 1),
      ('08-02-2016'
     , 1),
      ('08-03-2016'
     , 1),
      ('08-04-2016'
     , 1),
      ('08-05-2016'
     , 1),
      ('08-06-2016'
     , 2),
      ('08-07-2016'
     , 2),
      ('08-08-2016'
     , 2),
      ('08-09-2016'
     , 2.5),
      ('08-10-2016'
     , 1),
      ('08-11-2016'
     , 1);
```

QUERY:

```
;WITH Seq
    AS (SELECT SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Dates]
                                        , [Value])
            , t.Dates
            , t.[Value]
        FROM   #Temp t)
    SELECT StartDate = MIN([Dates])
        , EndDate = MAX([Dates])
        , [Value]
    FROM
          (SELECT [Value]
               , [Dates]
               , SeqNo
               , rn = SeqNo - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Value] ORDER BY SeqNo)
           FROM   Seq s) a
    GROUP BY [Value]
          , rn
    ORDER BY StartDate;
```

RESULTS:

[image]